# Disable Windows 7's "Open File - Security Warning" dialog for exe on network drive?

Tags: windows-7, security, network-shares

I have a mapped network drive, on which I store some programs, one of which I've put in my startup folder.

Unfortunately, this program "does not have a valid digital signature", which means that every time I reboot, I get a security dialog, asking me whether to run it.

I would prefer not to have to copy this program to the local disk.

How can I disable this prompt?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution.

- Go to Control Panel -> Internet Options -> Security -> Local Intranet -> Sites -> Advanced
- Add the mapped drive or UNC path (eg. Z:\ or \\machine)

Comment: Do I remember a box to tick for a permenant connection?

Comment: When mapping the drive, yes.

Comment: Thank you, this is the solution that allows me to finally use my shared VirtualBox folders to keep all of my portable windows utilities. It works on XP too.

Comment: Something may have changed (April 2014). The dialog won't let me add a drive letter, e.g. `X:\ ` and `X:` and `file://X:` all result in "you have entered an invalid wildcard sequence" (screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/um529J4.png) (Win7 Home Premium x64)

Comment: Is X actually a network drive? I just tested (win7 enterprise) - works for me with a mapped drive, but I get your error with a physical drive.

Comment: @matt wilkie To add a whole folder (in this case, the root folder), you should have to specify a wildcard at the target directory. So, it should look like `X:\*`. At least, this was the case in my experience.

Comment: For the sysadmins wondering what Reg Key is:
`HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Current Version\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Domains` and 
`HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Current Version\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Ranges`

Answer (score 6):

If your Internet Settings are tied down (as mine are), but you have access to the exe, you can try the following in a command prompt:

```
move oldName.exe > newName
type newName > oldName.exe
```

That will remove the stuff that causes Windows to care, which, I think, is stored in an alternate data stream.

Comment: Thanks, that worked even if I can't change settings in Internet Options

Comment: But probably there is mistake. This worked for me `move oldName.exe  newName` and `type newName > oldName.exe`

Answer (score 4):

The top answer didn't work for me I had to change a different setting in the same panel.

What I changed was:
From
Go to Control Panel -> Internet Options -> Security -> Local Intranet -> Sites -> Advanced
(Same as above)
In the "Local Intranet" settings window I unchecked "automatically detect intranet"
and checked "include all network paths"  which will work for me in my virtual environment.

[image: Local Intranet settings]

Answer (score 0):

You can use "automatically detect intranet" and then add the UNC path in the format of "file:\sharename" (if letters are mapped to this location, should work for them too)

Comment: Duplicate of the accepted answer

Comment: I disagree; all syntax variations in the "accepted answer" failed. This syntax works.

Comment: Disagree all you like. At the end of the day, the accepted answer got 39 upvotes and a check mark. All you got is a downvote. It means that answer worked and yours did not.

Comment: It's an important metric, however, I have found them to be either false or only containing part of the answer. Most of the time I must scroll down and see if someone addressed the errors in the original answer. What you are referring to is an Argumentum ad populum "...  a fallacious argument that concludes that a proposition is true because many or most people believe it: 'If many believe so, it is so.'" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argumentum_ad_populum