# Disable Open File security check Windows 10

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10, security, samba

I have not found a suitable solution for this:

> Open File security Check

For the record this is the security dialog I am referring to:

[image: Open File security check]

This is mounted as a network drive from a Raspberry Pi via a Samba share.

Since root can only mount, thus the owner of the file(s) is root as seen below:

[image: Security Tab]

There are a few questions and answers which refer to remving the security check completely for which ever file extension, this seems extremely unsafe.

Any suggestions for this?

*p.s. this is one on many files, thus setting a user for each file will take long and mess with meta data, as remove drive from a Windows and Linux as well as when plugged directly into my PC*

Comment: Does this help? http://superuser.com/questions/69863/disable-windows-7s-open-file-security-warning-dialog-for-exe-on-network-dri?rq=1 (or) http://windowsxp.mvps.org/networkfile.htm

Comment: @w32sh I cannot believe I missed that, you are a genius. I was knew it had to be around there but for some reason I missed it... please post your superuser link as answer. thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'm not supposed to post this as answer.. Instead want this issue marked duplicate... I think..

Comment: @w32sh beter, actually :p