# Disable Open File Security Warning for specific file types

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, internet-security

Windows likes to defend you against running executables that you have pulled from the web, and for some reason scripts like `.js` are included in that umbrella.
As a developer I have long-since swapped the associated program for javascript files from Windows Script Host to an editor, but the popups still persist.

[image: when double clicking a script from the web]

Unticking that box only disables the message for that specific file, and will come back to haunt you for every other file you hope to open from Explorer.
I have no intention of disabling the popup outright, like other questions already on SU want, so I'm asking my own; any ideas?

Maybe there's a list somewhere in the OS that registers `.js` as a potential script file that I could edit (changing the filename to `a.png`, for instance, while broken, opens the image viewer without any such warning).

Comment: As a developer, have you considered moving the pertinent files that you typically use to a different mapped drive and then exempting that specific drive accordingly?  [Disable “Open File - Security Warning” dialog on network drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/69863/disable-windows-7s-open-file-security-warning-dialog-for-exe-on-network-dri)

Comment: I saw that and fussing around with where everything is set up is not a palatable solution, not to mention that would enable `.exe`s et cetera on that drive to bypass the dialog (P.S you dont actually have to move anything, just create a virtual disk with those security settings, then create an NTFS junction inside it to your folder)

Answer (score 1):

For Windows 10 Pro you can use the below steps (might work for earlier versions but not tested on my end).

1. Open your Group Policy by pressing Windows Key + R on your keyboard and then entering gpedit.msc and pressing enter.
2. In the left pane navigate to User Configuration, Administrative Templates, Windows Components, Attachment Manager.
3. Double click on the "Inclusion list for low file types" policy and select Enabled and paste the following line in the Specify low-risk extensions input field: .js and click ok.

Solution reference and more info here: https://softkube.com/blog/how-disable-open-file-security-warnings-windows-file-type